# VBA Array Error 2007 if statement

Tags: vba, excel

Probably its a simple and common question but I did not find anything in google.
I store some data in array but sometimes this data has error value, in this case `xlErrDiv0 2007    #DIV/0!`

I use this array in a loop so i need to check if I loop through this incorrect value.

I tried:

```
If vRangeShift(1, i) <> CVErr(xlErrDiv0) Then
End if

If vRangeShift(1, i) = "Error 2007" Then
```

and some others options but I always receive type mismatch error.
`vRangeShift` is `Variant` type. The problems occurs only when I check this incorrect array element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do the trick:

`If IsError(vRangeShift(1, i)) Then`

Answer (score 0):

One approach among several would be to catch the error and handle it with some code further down.

```
On error goto HandleMyError
    'do something with vRangeShift(1, i)

'... more code here ....'
Cont:
    'finish out sub

Exit Sub 'Have this here so if there isn't an error, you can skip over
         'the error handler
HandleMyError:
    'if doing something with vRangeShift(1,i) produces an error, you 
    'you will end up here where you can handle the error as you see fit
    'once you've satisfactorily handled the error, you can return to 
    'that part of your code where you want the sub to continue
    Goto Cont

End Sub
```

Comment: For the purpose of this task I will just check if the array element has error value, yet for the whole macro I should integrate error handler like you proposed, thanks :)